# How to check whether there are newer versions of library dependencies in an sbt/play/activator project

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

Is there any command in Activator that can list all the dependencies and libraries that I use with the current version and newer versions that is possible to use to update my project?

This is similar that the apache maven command `versions:display-dependency-updates`.

Is there any similar command available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [sbt-updates](https://github.com/rtimush/sbt-updates), which is a plugin for sbt and activator.

Install the plugin and execute `activator dependencyUpdates` to see the list of outdated dependencies.